# Ajax error result with some input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here my HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="qty" size="30" />
<div id="ajax_result"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$('#qty').keyup(function(){
    var param = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {qty: param},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result){
                    $('#ajax_result').html(result);
                 },
        error: function(result){
                    $('#ajax_result').html('Error');
                },
    });
});
</script>
```

AJAX.php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['qty'])){
      echo 'AJAX OK';
  }
?>
```

The problem is the following:

if I insert e.g. '50' on `#qty` the function returns `AJAX OK`.

if I insert e.g. '5000' on `#qty` the function returns `Error`. Why?

EDIT:

Here the console:

[image: CONSOLE REQUEST]

Comment: The error is surely not because of the value 5000. Look at the console, whats the response code of that request. And how about the server logs?

Comment: because your server is returning status error. see the console for the response.

Comment: The problem is that the request with `qty=5000` is not sent

Comment: I tested your code and i couldnt find any problem with `5000`

Comment: I uploaded an image with the requests: the `5000` doesn't appear at all!

Comment: So by me: Internet Explorer works, Chrome doesn't works

Comment: Try entering directly the url `ajax.php?qty=5000` in the browser to see if it throws any error.

Comment: I have also test.. And its working fine with 5000.

Comment: Maybe it's my chrome that it's working bad? I'll try on another computer... On this computer works on IE, but not on Chrome... Entering directly `ajax.php?qty=5000` also works...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `dataType: ""` .

I have had this error some times and the datatype can be the solution.

[jQuery/ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)